# Python setuptools install_requires error

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm using setuptools to create a quick setup.py script to install dependencies for the user. The package only requires numpy and matlibplot. So the code looks something like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name = "somePackageName",
    version = "1.0",
    packages = ['doc', 'inputs', 'inputs', 'src'],
    install_requires = ['distribute == 0.7.3', 'numpy', 'matplotlib']
    )
```

running sudo python setup.py install gives me the following:

```
running install
Checking .pth file support in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
/usr/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST PASSED: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ appears to support .pth files
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating fabSim.egg-info
writing requirements to fabSim.egg-info/requires.txt
writing fabSim.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to fabSim.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to fabSim.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'fabSim.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'fabSim.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'fabSim.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/doc
copying doc/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/doc
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/inputs
copying inputs/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/inputs
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
copying src/simulation.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
copying src/good.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
copying src/producer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
copying src/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
copying src/validate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/doc
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/doc/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/doc
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/src
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/simulation.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/src
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/good.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/src
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/producer.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/src
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/src
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/validate.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/src
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/inputs
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/inputs/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/inputs
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/doc/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/src/simulation.py to simulation.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/src/good.py to good.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/src/producer.py to producer.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/src/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/src/validate.py to validate.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/inputs/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying fabSim.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying fabSim.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying fabSim.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying fabSim.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying fabSim.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating dist
creating 'dist/fabSim-1.0-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing fabSim-1.0-py2.7.egg
removing '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabSim-1.0-py2.7.egg' (and everything under it)
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabSim-1.0-py2.7.egg
Extracting fabSim-1.0-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
fabSim 1.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabSim-1.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for fabSim==1.0
Searching for matplotlib
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/
Reading http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706
Reading https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474
Reading https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=278194
Reading https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.99.1/
Reading http://matplotlib.org
Reading https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0.1/
Reading https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0
Reading https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.99.3/
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.1.0/
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.1.1/
Best match: matplotlib 1.3.0
Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.3.0/matplotlib-1.3.0.tar.gz
Processing matplotlib-1.3.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-xOXtid/matplotlib-1.3.0/setup.cfg
Running matplotlib-1.3.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-xOXtid/matplotlib-1.3.0/egg-dist-tmp-JFeCc4
The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available,
and can't be installed while this script is running. Please
install a more recent version first, using
'easy_install -U distribute'.

(Currently using distribute 0.6.28dev-r0 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages))
error: Setup script exited with 2
```

My understanding of setuptools is probably off as I expect it to update/install available dependencies from PyPI. Could someone provide additional insight on this?

Comment: Maybe you should uninstall Distribute and upgrade Setuptools and try again since both have merged (in Setuptools).

Comment: Why do you try to install Distribute if your package only depends on numpy and matplotlib? Also, what Stan said.

Comment: I also fell into this. As it seems from debugging this on Python 2.7, the command `python setup.py install` does not honor the `install_requires` specification (or `setup_requires`), but the command `pip install ...` does. However, `python setup.py develop` does install the dependencies, in preparation of a PyPi upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip install -U distribute
```

or

```
easy_install -U distribute
```